# Prevent ScrollViewer from changing its Content size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want the ScrollViewer to do only one thing - allow me to scroll. I don't want it to allow its Content to grow. Yet it does. How to prevent that?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="a.png"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="400"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If I comment out the ScrollViewer - the Image is small. If I leave the ScrollViewer - the Image grows. How to prevent that?

Comment: What - if anything - happens if you remove the `Stretch` property from the `Image` tag?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Doesn't change anything. You can try it with any image and see. I thought ScrollViewer isn't supposed to change its Content's size.

Comment: The Image grows as large as the "native size" of its Source, when there is enough space. To avoid that, set its Width and/or Height.

Comment: When you add `ScrollViewer` you allow the image to be scaled in height without restrictions, because scroll.

Comment: The same would happen with a StackPanel instead of the ScrollViewer. The point is that there is enough space available.

Comment: @Clemens `as large as the "native size" of its Source` - no. it grows even bigger. (Not that that's relevant, though.)

Comment: @Clemens `The same would happen with a StackPanel` - correct. But that's what's _supposed to happen_ with a StackPanel - to fit stuff in it. A ScrollViewer, on the other hand, serves a completely different purpose.

Comment: No, it is supposed to behave exactly like a StackPanel. Provide as much space as required by its child elements. Then make that area scrollable. Set the Image Height and you're done. Also check the Width and Height of the Source BitmapSource. They may not be identical to its PixelWidth and PixelHeight.

Comment: @Clemens `Provide as much space as required be its child elements.` - correct. And the `*` just means - whatever room is left. As for setting the Height etc. - The point is I don't want to limit that. I want it to have as much room as it needs, and if there's not enough - provide a scrollbar.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this. You should of course set `Stretch="None"` on the Image - the default is `Uniform`. And perhaps set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would avoid stretching the Image by setting its `Stretch` property to `None`.

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Stretch="None" .../>
```

The Grid and hence the Image element use the full width of the scrollable area. Since the default Stretch value is `Uniform`, the Image subsequently adjusts its height to keep its aspect ratio.

An equivalent, but simpler layout would be

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Stretch="None" Source="a.png"/>
        <Grid Height="400"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```